Optimize MSE with wildcard elements
Let's say you have a $n \times n$ matrix, for example, this $4 \times 4$ matrix:
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & d \\\ e & f & g & h \\\ i & j & k & l \\\ m & n & o & p \end{bmatrix}$$
and you want to compute a rank $r$ approximation of this matrix to minimize the MSE. Specifically you want to find two matrices $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times n}$ to minimize the objective function
$$ \min_{a, b} \| ab - M \|_F$$
where $\| \cdot \|_F$ is the Frobenius norm of the matrix (square each element in the matrix, take its sum, then square root the resulting sum). This objective function is equivalent to minimizing the MSE (mean-squared error) of the original matrix $M$.
Normally we can solve this analytically: we can use SVD to truncate away the lowest $(n-r)$ singular values, and the remaining $r$ resulting vectors and singular values are our analytical solution
But how do you compute the best rank $r$ approximation of this matrix (minimizing MSE) with wildcard elements? For example, if instead the matrix is:
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}a & * & c & * \\\ * & * & * & h \\\ i & j & * & l \\\ * & n & o & * \end{bmatrix}$$
and when calculating the MSE of the rank $r$ matrix, the error term associated with the wildcard elements do not count in the objective function? Specifically, the MSE calculation only considers the terms $a, c, h, i, j, l, n, \text{and } o$?
Another way to frame this problem is, how do you optimize the following (as an example):
$$ \min_{a, b} \| (ab) \cdot C - M \|_F \quad\quad\quad \text{(Hadamard product)} \\\\
\text{where }  \\\\
C = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
but more generally, the matrix $C$ can be any arbitrary binary matrix?
You can use an optimizer with gradient descent for the above, but I find that the local optima it finds isn't very good (initializing the matrices $a$ and $b$ with random entries). So the goal of this post is to find if there is a "better" way to solve for the above other than just naive gradient descent. Perhaps there is an "approximately analytical" solution that I can use to initialize the matrices $a$ and $b$ before performing gradient descent?
Additionally, I am curious to understand more on the theory behind this. For example, how do you even compute the gradient of the wildcards? Do the optimizer library just set them as $0$?

Hm. Here is the standard definition of the matrix 2-norm: $$||A||2 = \text{sup}{x\neq 0}\frac{||Ax||_2}{||x||_2}.$$ Every entry of $Mx$ in your example has a wildcard. Wouldn't this mean that all entries of $(ab-M)x$ "do not matter"? How would you even calculate a matrix norm here?

Sorry, you are correct. Matrix 2-norm is not the correct notation here. I wanted to write the mean-squared error, i.e. take the difference of every element, square the term, and sum them together. I will update it to the Frobenius norm

OK, that makes more sense. Perhaps add this to the question; not everyone is familiar with the Frobenius norm for matrices. Also, your bottom formula seems to be a little confused between $B$ and $C$, can you please clarify?

Thanks Stephan -- I have updated the questions to your suggestions
